# How to use dot notation in geo percolator

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation

I use Elasticsearch 2.2.1 for searching documents that relate to a specific geo graphic location (within a bouding box). I want to create a percolator that I can use to check if a new document relates to an existing query.

This works fine if I put the percolator into the index containing the documents but because of the issue mention in this [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html) and the workaround mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html#geo-percolate) I need to put the percolate queries into a dedicated percolator index.

When I try to put a percolator into this index:

```
PUT /mypercindex/.percolator/1
  {"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
    {"bool":
        {"should":
            [
                {"geo_bounding_box":
                    {"location.coordinates":
                        {"bottom_right":
                            {"lat":50.0,"lon":8.0}
                        ,"top_left":
                            {"lat":54.0,"lon":3.0}
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}}}
```

I get an error message saying that:

> Strict field resolution and no field mapping can be found for the field with name [location.coordinates]

In the percolator documentation is [mentioned](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html#dedicated-percolator) that, in case of a dedicated percolator index, you need to:

> make sure that the mappings from the normal index are also available on the percolate index

This may cause my issue but I cannot find the documentation about how to make the mapping from one index available in the other. I tried to add the dedicated percolator index with the same mapping as my document index but when I do this I still get the same error message.

The mapping of my document index resembles this:

```
{"my_mapping": {
  "dynamic":"strict",
  "properties":{
    "body":{
        "properties":{
            "author":{
                "type":"string",
                "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "hashtags":{
                "type":"string",
                "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "language":{
                "type":"string",
                "index":"not_analyzed"
            }
            ,"text":{
                "type":"string",
                "analyzer":"stopwords"
            },
            "title":{
                "type":"string",
                "analyzer":"stopwords"
            }
        }
    },
    "location":{
        "properties":{
            "coordinates":{
                "type":"geo_point"
            },
            "names":{
                "type":"string",
                "analyzer":"standard"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `.percolator` mapping to the mapping, like [mentioned in the Github issue that addresses this workaround](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16832), fixed the issue for me:

```
".percolator": {
  "dynamic": true,
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```